# Выбор алгоритма машинного обучения

Tags: алгоритм, машинное-обучение, классификация

Требуется построить классификатор. Элемент данных - вектор признаков. Каждый вектор очень разреженный, то есть большая часть элементов есть нули. Классов мало: всего 2-3.

Какой алгоритм лучше всего подойдёт?

Поможет ли здесь PCA для сокращения размерности?

В идеале хотелось бы иметь fuzzy классификатор, дающий вектор {p_i} вероятностей принадлежности к каждому классу.

Есть ли рекомендации по методам подбора алгоритма на основе экспериментов?

Comment: Ну чаще и проще всего используют алгоритмы на базе нейронов

Comment: Да, классификация хорошо реализуется на базе многослойного перцептрона!

Answer (score 4):

Для многих алгоритмов существуют классификаторы, умеющие работать с разреженными представлениями данных.

1. Сложно сказать, какой алгоритм подойдёт лучше. На практике случайные леса работают очень хорошо. scikit-learn умеет обучать их по разреженным данным.
2. PCA может помочь, но следует иметь в виду, что в его основе лежит предположение о том, что данные находятся на какой-то низкоразмерной линейной поверхности, "встроенной" в пространство, которое мы наблюдаем. Если это предположение нарушается, то и качество будет страдать.
3. Стандартная рекомендация: начать с простого (логистическая регрессия, решающие деревья), постепенно переходя к всё более сложным моделям (ансамбли и бустинг). По изменению качества можно понять, насколько вообще задача сложна. Ну а дальше всё зависит от вашего полёта фантазии — можно придумать новых признаков, а можно скрестить имеющиеся классификаторы (blending, stacking, например).

Comment: P.S. Да, я осознаю, что вопросу уже 4 года, но не оставлять же его неотвеченным.